# $AB+BA=(trB)A + (trA)B +(trAB - trAtrB)I_2 .$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A,B \in \mathbb{M}_2(\mathbb{F})$. I want to show that $$AB+BA=(trB)A + (trA)B +(trAB - trAtrB)I_2 .$$

I've tried to prove the assertion considering arbitrary two matrices $A,B$ in $\mathbb{M}_2(\mathbb{F})$. I have calculated $AB$ and $BA$. Then, I have obtained the equality above. However, it is too long and boring. Is there any short way?

Comment: Maybe you can assume SVD (Singular Value Decomposition) of A and B and see where that leads.

Answer (score 3):

We use Caley-Hamilton theorem, i.e. $X^2-{\rm tr}\ X \cdot X+{\rm
det}\ XI=0$, for $A+B$ :

For direct computation we have a claim $$ {\rm }
 {\rm tr }A \ {\rm tr}B- {\rm tr} (AB) =
 {\rm det} (A+B)- {\rm det}A- {\rm det} B $$

If $A=\left(
        \begin{array}{cc}
          a & b \\
          c & d \\
        \end{array}
      \right),\ B=\left(
                    \begin{array}{cc}
                      x & y \\
                      z & w \\
                    \end{array}
                  \right)$ then $$
{\rm det} (A+B)- {\rm det}A- {\rm det} B =aw +dx-bz-cy$$

Remaining thing is also followed from direct computation.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an answer that is light on computation but conceptually somewhat obscure.

If we perturb $A$ by some $\delta I_2$, both sides of the equality change by the same amount. The similar holds if we perturb $B$ by a scalar matrix. So, we may assume that both $A$ and $B$ are traceless. In this case, the equality reduces to
$$
AB+BA=\operatorname{tr}(AB)I_2\text{ when }\operatorname{tr}(A)=\operatorname{tr}(B)=0.\tag{1}
$$
As both sides are bilinear in $(A,B)$, it suffices to prove $(1)$ on any basis of the subspace of all traceless $2\times2$ matrices.

We want to show that $(1)$ is a *universal identity*. So, it suffices to consider only the case $\mathbb F=\mathbb C$ (for the reason, see e.g. p.4 of [the handout written by Keith Conrad](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/univid.pdf)). In particular, it suffices to prove it when $A$ and $B$ are some nonzero scalar multiples of [Pauli matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices) $\sigma_x,\sigma_y,\sigma_z$. Since the real linear span of $\{-i\sigma_x,-i\sigma_y,-i\sigma_z\}$ is isomorphic to the real algebra of quaternions under the isomorphism $-i\sigma_x\mapsto i,\ -i\sigma_y\mapsto j,\ -i\sigma_z\mapsto k$, equality $(1)$ further reduces to
$$
ab+ba=2\operatorname{Re}(ab),\quad a,b\in\{i,j,k\},\tag{2}
$$
which is completely trivial.

Comment: Very obscure indeed.

Answer (score 0):

In general, a matrix $X\in \mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{F})$ is determined by the linear map $\mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{F})\to \mathbb{F}$ defined by $Y\mapsto \operatorname{tr}(XY)$.  This is because if $E_{ij}$ is the $n\times n$ elementary matrix that's all $0$ except for a $1$ in the $(i,j)$ entry, then $\operatorname{tr}(XE_{ij})$ is the $(i,j)$ entry of $X$.

Thus, it suffices to show that for all $A,B,C\in \mathbb{M}_2(\mathbb{F})$ that
$$
\operatorname{tr}(ABC+BAC)=\operatorname{tr}((\operatorname{tr}B)AC + (\operatorname{tr}A)BC +(\operatorname{tr}(AB) - \operatorname{tr}A\operatorname{tr}B)C ).
$$
Applying linearity of trace, this is equivalently
$$
\operatorname{tr}ABC+\operatorname{tr}BAC=\operatorname{tr}B \operatorname{tr}(AC) + \operatorname{tr}A \operatorname{tr}(BC) +\operatorname{tr}(AB)\operatorname{tr}C - \operatorname{tr}A\operatorname{tr}B\operatorname{tr}C
$$
and just for sake of putting things in order to show how symmetric the situation is, this is
$$
\operatorname{tr}ABC+\operatorname{tr}CBA= \operatorname{tr}A \operatorname{tr}(BC) + \operatorname{tr}B \operatorname{tr}(CA) + \operatorname{tr}C\operatorname{tr}(AB) - \operatorname{tr}A\operatorname{tr}B\operatorname{tr}C.
$$
(The theoretical context here is that we have these two trilinear forms on $\mathbb{M}_2(\mathbb{F})$ that we want to show are equal.  In fact, these are trilinear forms invariant under the action of $GL(2)$ on $\mathbb{M}_2(\mathbb{F})$ by conjugation. The vector space of such invariant trilinear forms for general $GL(n)$ and $\mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{F})$ happens to be spanned by the six terms present in the above equation, and what we're wanting to show is that when $n=2$ that this spanning set is linearly dependent in this way. Linear dependence occurs exactly when $n=0,1,2$, and, fancifully, when $n=-1,-2$, otherwise the vector space of invariant trilinear forms is indeed 6-dimensional.)

Recall that the third exterior power of a two-dimensional vector space is zero-dimensional, i.e. $\bigwedge^3\mathbb{F}^2\approx 0$.  Regarding the exterior power as a subspace of $\mathbb{F}^2\otimes \mathbb{F}^2\otimes \mathbb{F}^2$, then the projection $p$ onto the third exterior power is given by
$$v_1\otimes v_2\otimes v_3 \mapsto \frac{1}{6}\sum_{\sigma\in S_3}(-1)^\sigma v_{\sigma(1)}\otimes v_{\sigma(2)}\otimes v_{\sigma(3)}$$
where $(-1)^\sigma\in\{-1,1\}$ is the sign of the permutation $\sigma$ in the symmetric group $S_3$ on three elements.  (If you care about finite-characteristic fields, you can get rid of the $\frac{1}{6}$, and it's ok using a scale multiple of a projection for the following.) Since the subspace is zero-dimensional, this projection function is identially zero, hence we get the identity
$$
v_1\otimes v_2 \otimes v_3 - v_1\otimes v_3 \otimes v_2 + v_2\otimes v_3 \otimes v_1 - v_2\otimes v_1 \otimes v_3 + v_3\otimes v_1 \otimes v_2 - v_3\otimes v_2 \otimes v_1 = 0
$$
for all $v_1,v_2,v_3\in\mathbb{F}^2$.

This next part is tricky to explain.  I'm staring at some [Penrose notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_graphical_notation) that convinced me of it, but I'll try to do it symbolically.  The idea is that we can take the three matrices as linear operators $\mathbb{F}^2\to\mathbb{F}^2$, tensor them together to get an operator $A\otimes B\otimes C:\mathbb{F}^2\otimes \mathbb{F}^2\otimes \mathbb{F}^2\to \mathbb{F}^2\otimes \mathbb{F}^2\otimes \mathbb{F}^2$, composing this with $p$, and then taking the trace.  Considering that $p=0$, we have
$$\operatorname{tr}(p\circ(A\otimes B\otimes C))=0.$$
Perhaps you can convince yourself that, using the expansion of $p$ into six permutations, that this is
$$
\operatorname{tr}A\operatorname{tr}B\operatorname{tr}C
- \operatorname{tr}A\operatorname{tr}(BC)
+ \operatorname{tr}(ABC)
- \operatorname{tr}C\operatorname{tr}(AB)
+ \operatorname{tr}(CBA)
- \operatorname{tr}B\operatorname{tr}(CA)
= 0
$$
which after moving some terms to the other side is exactly the equality we wanted to establish.  Sorry for the lack of details in this last step -- if anyone wants a Penrose diagram proof I can add it.